# solution method for polynomial equation

Tags: polynomials

I am looking for approximation methods for polynomial equations of this kind:

$$x^n -k\cdot x + (k-1) = 0$$

where $n\geq 5$ (typically $n=5, 10, 25, 50, 100$),

$k\in\mathbb{R^+}$,

and $1.05<x<1.15$

Any help is greatly appreciated. You can also just give me some keywords on methods and I will be able to do some further research myself (I hope); that's fine :)

Comment: Since the range of the required root is bounded, the secant method or bisection will work like a charm here.

Comment: I suggest Newton's method.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I decided to use Newton's method, simply because it is easier to code :D But I might try and use the secant method or bisection someday if I have time and feel like it; just to see which method is faster in my case.

Answer (score 1):

With the conditions as stated, often times there will be no root in the range you give. Since the derivative is $nx^{n-1}-k$, the only critical point occurs at $$b=\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{1/(n-1)}.$$ As $1$ is always a root and there is only one other root to the other side of $b$, whenever $k\leq n$ the only other root will be less than $1$.

For instance, to get a root in the range you want the root of the derivative should be between $1$ and $1.15$, imposing the constraint
$$
\left(\frac{k}{n}\right)^{1/(n-1)}\leq1.15;
$$
that is, you require
$$
\bbox[5px, border: 2px solid red]{k\leq n\,1.15^{n-1}.}
$$
Note that this is a necessary condition, but not sufficient, for a root to be in your range.

As for finding said root, Newton's method works very fast, with the recursion 
$$
\bbox[5pt, border: 2pt solid green]{x_{m+1}=x_m-\frac{x_m^n-kx_n+k-1}{nx_m^{n-1}-k}.}
$$
Newton's method has the advantage that most often you can start really far from the root and still get there.

*Caveat:* in this case, with only two roots, the choice of the starting point of the method is easy. In general, though, it could be really complicated, as [this example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method#Basins_of_attraction) shows.

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer! Newton's method works great.